# How to browse a website in an automated manner?

Tags: windows-7, macros

I would like to record a macro (of sorts) where I browse to a certain website, and click around on various things.

Then I'd like the macro replayed every so often (based on a schedule).  However, when I replay it, I don't want the browser to come up - I just want to visit the URLs without the browser being up.

Without breaking out a development tool and coding it, how would I accomplish this task?